# How to insert conditions into Global Custom Text?

Tags: 7, views

I am new to drupal and getting hang of it. I have a custom text in one of my view and I need to display the title based on a condition.
This is what I have right now,

```
 <h1>[title] | [field_annual_number] </h1>
```

But I need to display this only if the title doesn't contains the work "multi".
So basically, the pseudo code is like this,

```
if([title].contains('multi')) then <h1> [title] </h1> else <h1> [title] | [ Field_annual_number] </h1>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
TIA.
Srividhya

Comment: Please tell us what Drupal version you're using as the answer will change.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that. I am using drupal 7. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to the bottom of your **template.php** file (located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder)

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

      if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1"){

        if (strpos($vars['fields']['title']->content, 'multi') !== false) {
          $vars['fields']['title']->content = "<h1>" . $vars['fields']['title']->content . "</h1>";
        } else { 
          $vars['fields']['title']->content = "<h1>" . $vars['fields']['title']->raw . "|" . $vars['fields']['field_annual_number']->raw . "</h1>";
       }

      }

    }
```

- replace **themename** with your theme name
- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

Once you update your template.php file, don't forget to clear/flush your cache in Drupal to see changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am editing a block with in a view. This is the path, views/view/features_view/edit/block_5. Should I use the same method or anything different method. Thanks

Comment: @Srividhya the same method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I replace the entire custom text? Based on the condition, I need to replace the custom text itself.

Comment: @Srividhya sorry forgot to get back to you on this, you got everything you wanted?

Comment: Oh yeah. I had to update the entire global text so used this variable $vars['fields']['nothing']->content. Clearing the cache did the charm. Thanks a lot for your help.